# How to close a powershell gui windows form after the button is clicked?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, powershell, onclick, exit

i have a script which created a small windows gui form with buttons depending on the scenarios;

-> on clicking, these buttons open respective files on remote file shares;following is the code;

```
$run.Add_Click({Invoke-Expression "Powershell \\Fileshare\$Random_File.Doc"}.GetNewClosure())
```

-> my issue is eventhough after the click the file opens ; the form still hangs arround in the back ground; I want to know how to close it(and even better if i can close whole powershell too)  ; i tried to embed ";exit" inside invoke but it gave errors , is there any other way to do it?

Please ask me if any questions or clarifications required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect `Invoke-Item \\fileshare\$file` will work much better than running new PowerShell for any document you want to open.

To close the form you can add $this.Parent (?).Close()
or just reference $form variable - that also should work:

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$run = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point -Property @{
        X = 0
        Y = 0
    }
    Text = 'Run'
}
$run.Add_Click({
    Invoke-Item C:\Windows
    $form.Close()
})
$form.Controls.Add($run)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked,  but still couldnt close that gui form in background.